# Question about plug-in to manage releases (maven application)

Tags: java, maven, versioning

Needs a better control on releases. I would like to use this plug-in

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Anyone knows this plug. May recommend another?

Regards,
T.

Comment: You have more then ten questions without an accepted answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this plugin and I would use it again. You just need to run `mvn release:prepare release:perform`